# google charts with asp.net MCV

Tags: c#

I am trying to display a simple pie chart using google charts with MCV and after following countless tutorials, i am unsure why I am still getting a blank screen.

If I follow this tutorial, https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart  the pie chart will load, however when I try to send data from a database, i am always left with a blank screen

using the entity framework

```
public partial class DividendTracking
   {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Shares { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SharePrice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> amount { get; set; }
   }
```

My Contoller looks like this

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomelabEntities enties = new HomelabEntities();
        var result = enties.DividendTrackings.Where(x => x.Product != null).GroupBy(o => o.Product)
               .Select(g => new { product = g.Key, total = g.Sum(i => i.Shares) }).ToList();




        //return View(result);
        // return View((Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)));
        return View(new JsonResult { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
```

and finally my view looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'product');
  data.addColumn('number', 'amount');


  // don't forget to add JQuery in your view.
  $.getJSON("@Url.Action("/Home/Index")", null, function (result) {
      $.each(result, function (i, item) {
          data.addRow([item.product, item.amount]);
      });

      var options = {
          title: 'Shares',

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
       });
     }
    </script>

   <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Im am Not sure why the chart is showing as Blank

Answer (score 0):

> I have just added result.results in this code. could you please try this one.
>   You can also check using consol.log(result); method in which what you are getting.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'product');
  data.addColumn('number', 'amount');


  // don't forget to add JQuery in your view.
  $.getJSON("@Url.Action("/Home/Index")", null, function (result) {
      $.each(result.results, function (i, item) {
          data.addRow([item.product, item.amount]);
      });

      var options = {
          title: 'Shares',

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
       });
     }
    </script>

   <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Still showing up Blank but when i use the console.log(result) i get ReferenceError: result is not defined